# OneToMany and ManyToOne annotations cause me problems

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm kind of new with Spring Boot. I have a small application which has database. Database contains tables *device* and *borders*. One device can have many borders, but one border can have only one device. My problem is, that I'm not able to remove device from database, when it has a one or more borders. If device doesn't have any borders, I can remove it.

Here is how I have defined borders to device table.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="device_id")
private Collection<Borders> borders = new ArrayList<>();
```

And here is how I have defined devices in borders-table:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="device_id", updatable=false)
private Device device;
```

Here is my method from DeviceService-class, where device should be removed.

```
    @Transactional()
public Boolean deleteDevice(DeviceVM devParam) {
    User user = getLoginUser();

    return deviceRepository.findDeviceByUserIdAndName(user.getId(), devParam.getName())
        .map(dev -> {
            deviceRepository.delete(dev);
            return true;
        })
        .orElse( false );
}
```

As I said earlier, device can be removed, when it doesn't have any borders, but with borders, it can't. Hopefully someone can help me. Here is error message what I can see from server:

> 2016-10-26 16:31:16.092 ERROR 10016 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] f.l.kimionpomo.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Exception in fi.jurt.kimionpomo.web.rest.DeviceResource.deleteDevice() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement' and exception = 'could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement'
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)

Answer (score 0):

Remove device from borders table you don't have to write it. One to many in device table for borders is good enough to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, optional=false)
```

from @ManyToOne in border. I think you don't want to delete a device (parent) when you deleting a border (child). Also add:

```
mappedBy="device"
```

in @OneToMany annotation in device.